# High fee uniswap liquid add for my new erc20 token

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

Uniswap.Today I tried to add liquidity to my new ERC20 token, I chose a pair, set up a range, clicked add and I was asked for 0.2 ether gas fee, which is almost $350, why so much? And will liquidity be deducted from me the next time I add it?
Multicall

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.